# statistics confidence level

Tags: statistics, research

A survey was carried out to find out if the occurrence of different kinds of natural disasters varies from on part of the town to the other. The town was divided into two as center town and town outskirts, and the natural disasters were divided into tornadoes, lighting, and fires.The survey showed these results:

```
             Tornadoe     Lightning     Fires
 Town Center     10         220          120
 Town Outskirts  20         150          200
```

Do the above findings provide enough proof at 95 confidence level to indicate that the happening of natural disasters depends on the part of town?

I need some help as to how I would solve this question? so far, I thought I might need to set up a hypothesis and an alternative hypothesis, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply perform a chi-square test using a 2x3 contingency table. The result is a highly significant p value, confirming the hypothesis that differences exist between the two parts of the town.

Comment: I set my null hypothesis to "the happening of different natural disasters depends on the part of town". Is that correct? I found the chi square value to be 36.049. The level of significance using p=0.05 and df=2 is 5.99, So the chi square value is greater than 5.99, does that mean that I reject my null hypothesis? I am confused

Comment: The null hypothesis is that the distribution of disaster type does not differ in the two parts of the town.  Since the chi square is 36.05, with df 2 you obtain a p<0.0001. This means that you have to reject the null hypothesis. The distribution differs between the two parts of the town.